# TeraTerm Serial port usage vs Usage in my code

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, teraterm

I have been working on a project that sends serial commands to an LG TV. This is my code:

```
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>

#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QStringList>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    int argumentCount = QCoreApplication::arguments().size();
    QStringList argumentList = QCoreApplication::arguments();

    QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);

    /*if (argumentCount == 1) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Usage: %1 <serialportname> [baudrate]").arg(argumentList.first()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }*/

    QSerialPort serialPort;
    QString serialPortName = "com3";
    serialPort.setPortName(serialPortName);


    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serialPort.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    /*if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to open port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPortName).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }*/

    QFile dataFile("C:\\SerialCommand.dat");
    if (!dataFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to open file for reading") << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    QByteArray writeData(dataFile.readAll());
    dataFile.close();

    if (writeData.isEmpty()) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Either no data was currently available on the standard input for reading, or an error occurred for port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPortName).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    qint64 bytesWritten = serialPort.write(writeData);

    if (bytesWritten == -1) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to write the data to port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPortName).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    } else if (bytesWritten != writeData.size()) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to write all the data to port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPortName).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    } else if (!serialPort.waitForBytesWritten(5000)) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Operation timed out or an error occurred for port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPortName).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    standardOutput << QObject::tr("Data successfully sent to port %1").arg(serialPortName) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I restart my pc, I run the code and nothing happens.  After that, I open TeraTerm, send the file, and it works (turns off the TV [no, it does not toggle]). Then I disconnect the port in TeraTerm and run my code again, but this time it works as well!

I tried sending the file multiple times in one run using my code. I tried waiting for a long period of time after opening the serial port. I tried sending the file multiple times and waiting and reopening the file in between sendoffs. Nothing has worked.

TeraTerm is an open source project, but it is too advanced for me (a novice programmer) to navigate.[This](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en) is the link to the TeraTerm project page. If you spot any major differences between my code and TeraTerm's, I would very much appreciate you pointing it out.

Comment: If executing TeraTerm first helps your program to send/receive data properly, then the problem is that your program does not fully configure the serial port for its requirements.  If you're using a Unix/Linux host, then run the `stty -aF /dev/tty...` command at each stage of the *"When I restart my pc, I run the code..."*, especially before and after TeraTerm.  I don't use C++, but "setting" the baudrate, then opening the port twice, and commence writing/reading without any configuration  looks wrong.  And this is the code that *" I'm fairly certain that that is not where the issue lies"*?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, this is the same code. This code comes from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273827/serial-write-crashes-program-in-qt-c) post. I didn't write it. Also, if you look at the code more closely, the second 'open' is commented out. I am running this on Windows 10. What I don't understand is why after I disconnect the port in teraterm my code works fine. It almost seems like a permissions issue with the TV.